# Do the Sceptre of Darkness and/or Sanguine Horn work post-faction change?

Tags: werewolv.es

If someone has been targeted by Sceptre of Darkness or afflicted by Sanguine HOrn, and changes faction later, do they still remain seen as Demon/Wolf by seer-type intel? Or does the faction change 'override' the item's effect?

(faction change examples I can think of: familiarisation, recruitment into BMC, drunk sobering up, BMC rited into wolfpack, Heart of Fenrir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auras would remain on a player, even after becoming new roles.